# how to change temp directory files in codeigniter 3.0 dev?

Tags: php, codeigniter

when my project upgraded to codeigniter 3.0 dev , if a model using `$this->db->cache_on();` ,codeigniter building more folders in project root folder like  (controller name)+(controller function name). 
 for example if url is be `admin/addpost` codeigniter create folder by `admin+addpost` name in my root folder!!!

I changed `$config['cache_path']` and `$config['log_path'] = 'logs/';` and `$config['log_threshold'] = 0;` in config file But it did not change!

Where should I set up ?

Comment: Check the permissions for those folders.

Answer (score 0):

On the database config file you need to set the cache directory location (`$db['default']['cachedir']`); you need to have it for each connection group. To use the default cache directory you should use: `application/cache/`

You also have an option in the database config file to set a global caching settings to all supported queries with the `$db['default']['cache_on']` variable.

The config variables you referred to are not relevant to the DB caching system.